# Initial filter for Kendo UI grid does not start by itself

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

here is my code:

```
            var searchGridDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
            batch: true,
            pageSize: 20,
            schema: {
                model:{
                    fields:{
                        ReportId: { type: "number" },
                        ReportDetails: { type: "string" },
                        DuReportDate: { type: "date" },
                        CompanyId: { type: "number" },
                        CompanyName: { type: "string" },
                    }
                }
            },
            transport: {
                read: {
                    url: actions.common.rootUrl + "api/AllDueReports/",
                    type: "Get"
            },

            ...
            ...
            ...
            sort: { field: "DuReportDate", dir: "asc" },
            filter: { field: "DuReportDate", operator: "lt", value: "01.01.2017" }
    });
```

On intialization of the grid, the hourglass does not go away and no records are displayed. Clicking on the filter symbol in the column header, the filter dialog opens and the correct filter date (01.01.2017) is present in the first date box.

Clicking on Filter -> the sandbox goes away and
1.) Records are displayed 2.) Records are sorted correctly, and 3.) Records are filtered correctly

Is there something I missed? What do I have to change/add that the filter process starts by itself?

Regards, Manu

Comment: Usually when the progress indicator does not go away, there is some kind of javascript error that has halted execution.  What do the devtools say?

Comment: @The Dread Pirate Stephen: What do you mean by 'devtools', or should I look into the kendo documentation?

Comment: your browser devtools..."Developer tools" in chrome, "F12 Developer tools" in IE/Edge, etc.  The place where you observe and debug all your client-side html/css/javascript.

Comment: @The Dread Pirate Stephen: Ah, I will check. Thanks.